# How to create a data type with value constructor containing list of type parameter types

Tags: haskell, type-parameter

I have a data structure with a type parameter called `Fluent`.
I want a list of these. What's the most elegant way to fix this code?

```
data Fluent t = Fluent [t]
data Obj = Obj [Fluent]
```

Edit: I want to be able to do this:

```
f1 = Fluent [True, False]
f2 = Fluent [1, 2, 3, 4]
let o = Obj [f1, f2]
```

Comment: Your example shows how one could construct an `Obj` value. What about elimination/destruction? I.e., how do you expect to _use_ a value of type `Obj`? If you access its innermost elements, they are of an unknown type, so you can't do anything with them which requires static types (i.e. everything). So, you either need to use `Dynamic` types, or some more precise `Obj/Fluent` types which keep some type information (possibly with a GADT, but it's hard to tell).

Answer (score 3):

You have to propagate the type parameter `t` up to the Obj type:

```
data Fluent t = Fluent [t]
data Obj t = Obj [Fluent t]

:t Obj $ map Fluent ["a", "bcd"] -- Obj Char
```

Comment: I don't want the same type for each `Fluent` in the list

Comment: @BinRoot Try this experiment: pretend someone has fixed Obj for you already, and then write out a sample expression you wish you could use, along with its type. Notice I did the same in my example. If we knew how you wished your type behaved, it would be less guesswork to try to provide solutions.

Comment: @BinRoot If you completely lose the information about what `t` is, an `Obj` becomes a list of lists of unknown things. There's not much you can do with such a list. In your example, assuming it worked, no one can actually access `o` beyond counting the number of elements. This is because e.g. `head (head o)` would be of an unknown type, so you can not use it anywhere.

Comment: If you really want, you can use an `HList` or some such, but that's a big hammer. What's your actual purpose?